# How to sign ipa after patch?

Tags: ios, ipa, codesign

I using MachoProtector https://github.com/pandazheng/MachOProtecter to remove some code from header, it work, but when re-sign, any tool cant sign it again. Any suggestion??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can sign ipa with this tool https://github.com/DanTheMan827/ios-app-signer

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. It show "The binary was modified" :-s